# Windows internet shortcuts hijacked?

Tags: windows-7, windows, google-chrome, hijack

So, i was helping out someone with her laptop (it has Windows 7 Ultimate, not sure 32 or 64 bit) and she has a browser hijack. I cleaned most of it, however, Windows internet shortcuts don't open the right page, but the page from the hijack. The question is: how do I solve this? The browser she is using is Google Chrome.

Edit: I meant when under New-Shortcut and make it lead to a website, it opens the bad page.

Answer (score 0):

Right-click the shortcut of Google Chrome (on the Desktop and than in the start menu) and click on settings. Remove the URL at the end of the path and click ok. After changing both shortcuts everything should be fine again.

Comment: Sorry, but this works fine. I mean .URL files

Comment: Search the registry for the URL the browser opens. Especially look at this key: HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\http\shell\open\command

Comment: Chrome also allows you to open pages that are not your "home" page on first start. In Chrome Settings, check under On Startup for any records of the hijack page, particularly under "Open a specific set of pages".